# How to construct ClassTag for Spark SQL DataFrame Mapping?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, rdd

Spark SQL 1.2.0 queries return JavaRDD. Spark SQL 1.3.0 queries return DataFrame.  Converting DataFrame to JavaRDD by DataFrame.toJavaRDD seems to take quite bit of time. I tried to use the DataFrame.map() and got a puzzling problem:

```
DataFrame df = sqlSC.sql(sql);
RDD<String> rdd = df.map(new AbstractFunction1<Row, String> (){

        @Override
        public String apply(Row t1) {
            return t1.getString(0);
        }


    }, ?);
```

"?" should be scala.reflect.ClassTag. I used ClassManifestFactory.fromClass(String.class) and it didn't work. What should I put at "?".

By the way, the example given by http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html's **Interoperating with RDDs** section Java Code is not corrected: It used "map(new Function() {". The "Function" is not acceptable there. It should be "Function1".

Comment: This is an issue with Java 8 for Spark which depends on EsotericSoftware/reflectasm (Currently only supports Java 7) 
: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6152.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
RDD<String> rdd = df.map(new AbstractFunction1<Row, String> (){

    @Override
    public String apply(Row t1) {
        return t1.getString(0);
    }


}, scala.reflect.ClassManifestFactory.fromClass(String.class));
```

Comment: this works for spark-2.4.5_2.12

Answer (score 1):

try this:(worked for me)

```
RDD<String> rdd = df.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String> (){

@Override
public String call(Row t1) {
    return t1.getString(0);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RDD<String> rdd = df.map(new AbstractFunction1<Row, String> (){

    @Override
    public String apply(Row t1) {
        return t1.getString(0);
    }

}, ClassManifestFactory$.MODULE$.fromClass(String.class));
```